# Почему выражение не сравнивается с шаблоном в case match?

Tags: python, match, python-3.10, python-3.11

Python 3.11. Пример кода:

```py
number = 1
num1 = 2
num2 = 4
num3 = 1

match number:
    case num1:
        print("num1")
    case num2:
        print("num2")
    case num3:
        print("num3")
    case _:
        print("number")
```

Получаю ошибку:

```
case num1:
     ^^^^
SyntaxError: name capture 'num1' makes remaining patterns unreachable
```

Почему 'num1' делает остальные шаблоны недоступными?

Но если заменить переменные num1, num2, num3 на строки, например "num1" и т.д., то все работает, т.е. сравнение со строкой выполняется, а сравнение с переменной не проходит, почему?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Имя переменной в предложении case рассматривается как [шаблон захвата имени](https://peps.python.org/pep-0634/#capture-patterns).

Вы можете создать класс с вашими атрибутами, это должно решить вашу проблему.

```py
class Number:
    num1 = 1
    num4 = 4


number = 1
match number:
    case Number.num1:
        print("num1")
    case Number.num4:
        print('num 4')
```

Comment: не совсем понял, можно подробней ... для особо одаренных :)

Comment: Подробная статья https://habr.com/ru/company/yandex_praktikum/blog/547902/

Comment: Если помогло отметьте как правильный ответ

Answer (score 0):

> Почему 'num1' делает остальные шаблоны недоступными?

Потому что переменная num1, захватывает значение number, без условий, теперь num1 равна number, естественно после этого другие шаблоны не доступны.

> Но если заменить переменные num1, num2, num3 на строки, например "num1" и т.д., то все работает, т.е. сравнение со строкой выполняется, а сравнение с переменной не проходит, почему?

Потому что в этом конкретном случае, происходит сравнение по строкам, так же может происходить сравнение по буквам, числам или булевым значениям.